# Selecting column with variable width

Tags: notepad++

Let's say I have a tab delimited text file like this:

```
111111111111111111111111111111  a
1   b
```

Is there a way to get the second column, i.e.

```
a
b
```

in notepad++?

I'm aware of `Alt + Drag` and `Shift + Alt + Arrow keys`, but I can only select

```
111111111111111111111111    a
b
```

Comment: Honestly, the easiest thing to do here is probably copy your text into a spreadsheet application that treats tabs as cell boundaries (Google Sheets, Excel, etc.) and then just copy the column you want. I'm not aware of a way to do what you're trying to do in Notepad++.

Comment: Oh, neat. I didn't realize that you could copy and paste tab separated text into excel and have it formatted already. Thank you for the input. It's a good solution for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^[^\t]*\t([^\t]+)$`
- Replace with: `$1`

This will keep what is between the first and the second tabulation (or end of line).

Comment: When I do this, the first line is `a`, which is good, but the second line is `1` instead of `b`.

Comment: I think part of my problem is that I had the ". matches newline" box checked. But I still had to change your regex to `^[^\t]*\t([^\t\n]+).*` to get it to work for me.

Comment: @blakeoft: Yes, you mustn't check `dot matches newline`, I've forgotten give this precision.

Comment: I'm at an impasse. I want to accept your answer, but your regex doesn't actually work for me. I think that `[^\t]` parts are picking up the new lines.

Comment: @blakeoft: See my edit, remove the `.*` from the end and add a `$`.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way that I have used in the past is to open the file in a text editor (notepad) and do a find replace on tabs (replace with commas). Before this get rid of any commas using the find/replace (ctrl+H)

then open the resulting csv file in excel.